# How can I access the dependencies of an application from within the build file of a dependency embedded in the application?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle-based library that is imported as a dependency into consuming applications. In other words, an application that consumes my library will have a `build.gradle` file with a list of dependencies that includes **both my library as well as any other dependencies they wish to import.**

From within my library's `build.gradle` file, I need to write a Gradle task that can access the full set of dependencies declared *by the consuming application*. In theory, this should be pretty straightforward, but hours of searching has not yielded a working solution yet.

The closest I've come is to follow [this example](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/write-projects-dependencies-to-file/9775) and define an additional task in the library's `build.gradle` file that runs after the library is built:

```
build {
    doLast {
        project.getConfigurations().getByName('runtime')
                .resolvedConfiguration
                .firstLevelModuleDependencies
                .each { println(it.name) }
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error message that the 'runtime' configuration (passed into `getByName` and referenced in the Gradle forum post I linked) cannot be found. I have tried other common Gradle configurations that I can think of, but I never get any dependencies back from this code.

So: what is the best way to access the full set of dependencies declared by a consuming application from within the build file of one of those dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I mostly figured it out. The code snippet is essentially correct, but  the configuration I should have been accessing was 'compileClasspath' or 'runtimeClasspath', not 'runtime'. [This page](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/dependency_management_attribute_based_matching.html?_ga=2.190882671.450420614.1649698536-665801733.1649268619#sec:abm_configuration_attributes) helped me understand the configuration I was looking for.

The final build task in the library looks roughly like this:

```
build {
    doLast {
        // ...
        def deps = project.getConfigurations().getByName('compileClasspath')
                .resolvedConfiguration
                .firstLevelModuleDependencies
                .each {
                    // it.name will give you the dependency in the standard Gradle format (e.g."org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.22.RELEASE")
                }
    }
}
```